# Попадание точки в закрашенную область на графике.

Tags: математика, pascal, график, c++, функции

Написать программу, которая определяет, попадает ли точка с заданными координатами в область, закрашенную на рисунке серым цветом. Результат работы вывести в текстовом сообщении.

Для данного графика у меня нет идей, точнее я не знаю какими уравнениями описывать заштрихованную область и как их составить.

Техническая реализация не составит проблем, **интересует только аналитическая форма или псевдокод, как составить нужное уравнение и(или) проверить нужную область?**
  [image]

Comment: Проводите луч из точки извне графика через заданную точку. Считаете пересечения луча с границами закрашенной области. Если количество пересечений от начальной точки до заданной нечётное, то, скорее всего, заданная точка находится внутри области. По возможности луч желательно проводить параллельно оси абсцисс или ординат.

Comment: @xHunter, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Мое предположение следующее: если точка попадает в квадрат то мы будет проверять далее окружности по формуле

```
 if sqr(x-x0)+sqr(y-y0)<=sqr(r) then count:=true
                                else count:=false
```

Проверяем попадает ли точка в одну окружность, а потом тем же путем проверяем другую.
Следовательно, если точка попадает в одну из окружностей она не попадает в закрашенную область.

Answer (score 4):

Разбейте задачу на простые подзадачи.

1. Точка принадлежит закрашенной области, если она принадлежит квадрату и НЕ принадлежит кругам.
2. Точка принадлежит квадрату, если её X-координата лежит в (*каких?*) пределах, а Y-координата лежит в (*каких?*) пределах.
3. Точка принадлежит окружности, если её расстояние от центра окружности не превосходит радиус
4. Расстояние между двумя точками считается по теореме Пифагора.

---

(*Да, можно соптимизировать, перейдя к квадратам расстояний, это не важно на данном этапе.*)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Point
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    // сгенерируйте сами геттеры, сеттеры и конструктор
}

Boolean withinCircle(Point arg, Point circleCenter,int radius)
{
 return sqr(arg.getX()-circleCenter.getX())+sqr(arg.getY()-circleCenter.getY())<=sqr(radius)
}

Boolean withinSquare(Point arg, Point leftUp, Point rightDown)
{
return (arg.getX()>=leftUp.getX()&&arg.getY()>=leftUp.getY())&&
(arg.getX()<=rightDown.getX()&&arg.getY()<=rightDown.getY())
}

Point yourPoint=...blah-blah
if(  !withinCircle(yourPoint,...) && !withinCircle(yourPoint,...) &&                withinSquare(yourPoint,...) )
```

Либо можно функции проверки принадлежности областям переместить в классы точек, либо сделать какой нибудь интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

```
function inD(x,y:double):boolean;
begin
  if (-R<=x) and (x<=R) and (-R<=y) and (y<=R)                  // в квадрате
     and ((-R-x)*(-R-x)+(R-y)*(R-y)>R*R)          // вне круга
     and ((R-x)*(R-x)+(-R-y)*(-R-y)>R*R) then     // вне круга
    result:=true
  else
    result:=false;
end;
```